# Documentation of bounties

Tags: discusión, soporte, recompensas

I noticed that a site participant put a huge (400) bounty recently on an oldish [question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/913/9385).  I've only touched the surface of that Q&A page, and am planning on spending some time digging into it, but I would have liked to start by reading the Bounty notice (is there some way of retrieving that now, or is gone forever?) and also a comment explaining the choice of answer to award the bounty to.

When I place a bounty, I generally do write a comment like that.  (Exception: if I've placed a bounty to draw more attention, but no new answers have been contributed.)  I couldn't find such a comment in this case, however.

I invite this bounty placer to write such a comment, since for me it would be a great place to start in reading the whole page; and I'd like to propose that here at Spanish Language Beta SE, at least, we take it as best practice to write an explanatory comment when awarding the bounty.

Es decir, si pones un bounty, por favor, que documentes con comentarios el porqué del bounty y el porqué de tu decisión.

Comment: @AndrewT. - I'm glad to have learned that trick, thank you.  If you post this as an answer I will be happy to accept it. I'm curious -- how did you come across this question?  Also, how do you manage to raise so many flags at the sites where you have a small rep?  I'm very impressed.

Comment: Well, I sometimes lurk to other sites and their meta for my curiosity... thus I found this question. Regarding flags, I'm usually hanging out on [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta), a chat room on Meta SE where there's a bot called Smoke Detector for reporting spam/offensive posts and users flagging from there :)

Comment: @AndrewT. - What was posted there related to Spanish.SE that you saw?

Comment: Smoke Detector has a dashboard called Metasmoke where it lists all the caught posts. [Here are all the caught posts on Spanish.SE](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?autoflagged=&body=&commit=Search&feedback=&post_type=&reason=&site=130&title=&user_rep_direction=%3E%3D&user_reputation=0&username=&utf8=%E2%9C%93&why=). Note that there are "true positives" (posts correctly identified as spam/offensive) and "false positives" (posts incorrectly identified as spam/offensive, usually on questions having vulgar context). "True positives" posts got flagged, while "false positives" are ignored.

Comment: @AndrewT. - That is interesting.  When you say "got flagged" and "are ignored," are you still talking about an automated process?  // What exactly was the smoke detected post that you saw, and what triggered the automatic detection in that case?  I'm curious to understand how this works, thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid this will take quite a while, it might be better if I direct you to [Charcoal's official site](https://charcoal-se.org/) for the introduction to Smoke Detector. Note that I'm not in their team, I only know as much as I know. Otherwise, you can consult most of the team members on [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540), their SE chat room.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would have liked to start by reading the Bounty notice (is there some way of retrieving that now, or is gone forever?)

There's a <s>non-</s>documented feature called [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36303/feedback-request-new-timeline-question-view) for each post that shows the public activity timeline, including bounty placement.

Format: `https://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/{id}/timeline`.

For the question mentioned on this post, [its timeline](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/913/timeline) stated:

- On Apr 18 '18, user19118* placed a bounty of 50 for "Canonical answer required", which they gave it to [Konamiman's answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/10485/8656).
- On May 27 '18, user19024* placed a bounty of 400 for "Rewarding existing answer", which they gave it to [Javi's answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/915/8656).

*Deleted users will only show their user ID, and the tooltip on the bounty will show "Community" instead.

---

> and also a comment explaining the choice of answer to award the bounty to.

While it might be good to explain the reason/commend the answer by commenting when awarding the bounty, it's never a requirement.

In the end, it might be a good practice (perhaps to encourage other answerers to put more effort), but just like comment on downvote, it's not enforceable. (although the difference is that downvote is anonymous while bounty is public)

---

> I invite this bounty placer to write such a comment

Unfortunately, just as I stated above, the accounts have been deleted, so the real reason will be a mystery forever...

Comment: It has little documentation and [little advertising](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126447/209901), but it was documented some time ago: [Feedback Request: New Timeline Question View](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36303/209901)